# Find button or label inside Griview using Nativescript Grid view

Tags: nativescript

I using GridView Nativescript to arrange the UI and I want to set css into specific button or label dynamically. How can I find inside label when outside button is trigger and I tried using getViewById method but always get empty result. Isn't got any method to find it ?

```
var gridview;
  exports.onPageLoaded = function (args) {
    page = args.object;
    gridview =  page.getViewById("gridview");

};

exports.onSelectedIndexChanged = function(args){
    var totalMatch = 0;
    var btn = args.object;
    var index = btn.index;

   var a = gridview.getViewById("25");

    btn.backgroundColor = "red";
    btn.color = "white";  
};


<GridLayout columns="*,1,*,1,*" rows="auto" borderWidth="1" borderColor="#DBDBDB" borderRadius = "3" >
            <Button text="selectALL" index="0" tap="onSelectedIndexChanged" backgroundColor= "red" id ="btnSelectAll" color="white" borderRadius="3" />
            <Button text="UnselectAll" index="1" col="2"  tap="onSelectedIndexChanged" backgroundColor= "white" id ="btnUnSelectAll" borderRadius = "3" />
            <Border col="1" borderWidth="1"  borderColor="#DBDBDB" />
            <Border col="3" borderWidth="1"  borderColor="#DBDBDB" />
        </GridLayout>   
    <gv:GridView items="{{ items }}"  verticalSpacing="3" horizontalSpacing="3" colWidth="100" rowHeight="50" padding="3" id="gridview" height="400">
                  <gv:GridView.itemTemplate>
                    <GridLayout backgroundColor="#ffffff" style="border-width:3px;border-color:#696969;border-radius:5">
                      <Button text="{{ Name }}" id="{{ Id }}" index="{{ Index }}" tap="onGridViewItemTap" backgroundColor= "white" color="red" style="background-size:100% 100%;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-image:url('~/images/drawable-hdpi-v4/spt_fiter_checked.png')"  borderWidth="1"  borderColor="#DBDBDB" borderRadius = "5"/>
                    </GridLayout>
                  </gv:GridView.itemTemplate>
                </gv:GridView>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please review your code so that it is more clear what you have tried to do. First - I don't see  where the `onSelectedIndexChanged`is used in the XML. Second - are you using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-grid-view.

Comment: ya, I'm using nativescript-grid-view and I really update code. Sorry for show unclear info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my understanding, what you are trying to do is:

- press the button in the GridLayout
- trigger the `onSelectedIndexChanged` function
- Access the button with id="25"
- Modify the button

First, I would like to point out that it is not recommended to access views by ids, especially when you have a complex UI structure. I would suggest that you use bindings. I am not sure what exactly you would like to modify, so I will assume that you would like to change the background property of the button. In this case, you can bind an Observable object in the code to the background property in the XML. Then in the function `onSelectedIndexChanged`, you can modify the object in the code by setting a new color. Since it is observable, it will notify all of the listeners for the modification. And in our case - the property in the XML.
Here I am sending you a simple example:

**main-page.xml**

```
 <Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="onPageLoaded">
   <GridLayout  rows="auto,auto" >
      <Button text="Click to Change Color" row="0" tap="onSelectedIndexChanged"/>
      <Button text="Button" row="1" backgroundColor="{{color}}"/>
   </GridLayout> 
 </Page>
```

**main-page.js**

```
var observable = require("data/observable");
var json={color:'red'};
var changeCss = new observable.Observable(json);

var gridview;
  exports.onPageLoaded = function (args) {
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext=changeCss;
};

exports.onSelectedIndexChanged = function(args){
  changeCss.set("color","blue");
};
```

I hope this will give you some directions.